# Problems making a deb package out of a Python script

Tags: python, ubuntu-14.04, packaging, deb

I have read a lot of guides about creating a .deb package, but so far I haven't been able to succeed. I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 and the location of the tar.gz file and .py files are in:

```
/home/nyoa/trafgen6/trafgen6-1.0#
```

The folder contains following files:

```
root@nyoa-VirtualBox:/home/nyoa/trafgen6/trafgen6-1.0# ls
DEBIAN  trafgen6-1.tar.gz  trafgen6.py
```

DEBIAN is folder where the files guiding the packaging should be. My question is what do I do next to achieve the following result:

Python script is installed so it can be started by only typing trafgen6 on command line and the name of the package is Trafgen6 (For some reason it is only Trafgen when I have tried to do it previously). The package should also depend on PyQt4 and Qwt.

The package isn't meant for public release yet so I don't need to worry about licenses and all the package details to be correct. I only need to be able to install it easily.

Thank you in advance for any advice you can give

Comment: Did you try this one?
http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the metadata inside DEBIAN is correct, and the install simply requires copying the files to the appropriate locations, all you need is to set up your fs hierarchy properly.

Should look like

```
DEBIAN/control
usr/bin/trafgen6 -- python script which sets os.cwd, imports and launches program
usr/lib/python<version>/dist-packages/trafgen6/ -- directory containing all trafgen6 associated files (perhaps try unpacking your .gz here.
```

When you install the package, it will copy them to /
To assemble the debian package, go into /home/nyoa/trafgen6/trafgen6-1.0#
 and run dpkg-buildpackage . ..
It will kick out the debian package in /home/nyoa/trafgen6.

Comment: Obviously <version> should be the python version you're using, 2.7, 3.4, et cetera.

Comment: At the moment I don't have any files in the DEBIAN folder because after failing to first make them myself and then failing to make the package with the helper script I deleted everything. What is the bare minimum I need to be able to create a .deb package? Do I only add those two lines in DEBIAN/control file or do I need to add a line such as Install before them?

Comment: Bare minimum for the DEBIAN folder is `prerm` and `postinst` files with permissions 755 that must exit 0, and a `control` file containing `Package: ` and the package name, `Version: `and some version number.  It's also good to include maintainer, architecture, section, priority, depends, conflicts, and description entries, but a package without those should still build.  If you unpack an existing simple package, you can modify the existing scripts and control file for a new package.